# Intent error - process stop unexpectdly

Tags: android, android-intent

I need some help in my application. I have these classes:

`Ajuda.class`:

```
public class Ajuda extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ajuda);
    }
}
```

`testes.class`:

```
public class teste extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.mnuAjuda:
            Intent i = new Intent (this.getApplicationContext(),
                                   Ajuda.class);
            this.startActivity(i);
            return true;
        default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

On method `onOptionsItemSelected` in `case R.id.mnuAjuda`:   if I got

```
Intent i = new Intent (this.getApplicationContext(),  
    Ajuda.class);  
    this.startActivity(i);
```

instead of

```
setContentView(R.layout.ajuda);
```

the application stop unexpectdly and I dont know why.

Comment: what is the error you are getting in Logcat.

Comment: No, maybe the title is not the right thing, but instead of a error, my app crashes when i press "Ajuda" (Menu Item) and i dont see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you put something like

```
<activity android:name=".Ajuda" android:label="Ajuda" />
```

in **AndroidManifest.xml**?